# Ogre3d: iterating through childnode error

Tags: c++, iteration, ogre, ogre3d

I have a city node which houses many building nodes, each of these I wish to grant a new child-node. which tells the house what role and  sign they have/role. Which can later be used for other functions. for now all get the same .mesh (will later make a sign) to identify which house is what. it shall be randomly assigned. If I try to run this I get the following error. I am very new  to ogre , which adds to some weird code

[image: error when trying to launch]

```
int CityManager::assignBuildingRole(Ogre::SceneNode * _cityNode, int _numberOfBuildings)
{
    std::stringstream nodename("buildingRoleNode");
    Ogre::SceneNode::ChildNodeIterator cNode = _cityNode->getChildIterator();
    std::vector <Ogre::SceneNode*> detachable;
    while (cNode.hasMoreElements()) {
        detachable.push_back((Ogre::SceneNode *)cNode.getNext());
    }
        for (int i = 0; i < detachable.size(); i++) {
            nodename << childIteration << "_" << parentIteration << "_" << i;
            switch (rand() % 5) // assign building random proffessions by giving them a rolenode
            {
            case 0:
                _roleNode = ( Ogre::SceneNode *)cNode.getNext()->createChild(nodename.str());
                _signEntity = manager->createEntity("Barrel.mesh");
                _roleNode->attachObject(_signEntity);
                break;
            case 1:
                _roleNode = (Ogre::SceneNode *)cNode.getNext()->createChild(nodename.str());
                _signEntity = manager->createEntity("Barrel.mesh");
                _roleNode->attachObject(_signEntity);
                break;
            case 2:
                _roleNode = (Ogre::SceneNode *)cNode.getNext()->createChild(nodename.str());
                _signEntity = manager->createEntity("Barrel.mesh");
                _roleNode->attachObject(_signEntity);
                break;
            case 3:
                _roleNode = (Ogre::SceneNode *)cNode.getNext()->createChild(nodename.str());
                _signEntity = manager->createEntity("Barrel.mesh");
                _roleNode->attachObject(_signEntity);
                break;
            case 4:
                _roleNode = (Ogre::SceneNode *)cNode.getNext()->createChild(nodename.str());
                _signEntity = manager->createEntity("Barrel.mesh");
                _roleNode->attachObject(_signEntity);
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }

    return role;
}
```

Comment: `getNext` not only retrieves the next child node, but _advances_ the iterator, too. see its [docs](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/1.9/class_ogre_1_1_map_iterator.html#a2bef2d340ae00274856261b3ad3dcdbc). changing them to `peekNextValue` may solve your problem

Comment: Also, see the comment [here](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/1.9/class_ogre_1_1_node.html#ad8236bbe5857e6e8683b35989a43d774): "Note that the returned iterator is only valid whilst no children are added or removed from this node", witch is the same behaviour as for any stl iterator

Comment: Does this mean I cannot iterate through my childnodes of cityNode to add extra nodes this way? or will peekNextValue resolve this issue?

Comment: why don't you iterate through `detachable`? just calling `detachable[i]->createChild`

Comment: Sorry for the slow response, building takes ages, thank you. I get no errors and it worked. `peekNextValue` simply stopped after the first city (or just didn't go to the next)

Comment: i'll formulate an answer

Comment: `peekNextValue` was a wrong guess for solution. However it really doesn't go to the next it just peeks it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `getNext` on `ChildNodeIterator` will not only retrieve the next element but *advance* to the next element, too. See its description in [documentation](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/1.9/class_ogre_1_1_map_iterator.html#a2bef2d340ae00274856261b3ad3dcdbc)

So what you do is iterating over the children of `_cityNode` and store every child in your `detachable` vector.

```
while (cNode.hasMoreElements()) {
  detachable.push_back((Ogre::SceneNode *)cNode.getNext());
}
```

After these lines your `cNode` points to end of children list (specifically *after* the last element, as `end()` in `std::map` which is the underlying data type)

If you are trying to iterate it further you'll get an error.

You can either use `detachable` for the next iteration (I guess that's why you created it)

```
_roleNode = detachable[i]->createChild(nodename.str());
```

or do the child creation in your while loop and don't use `detachable` at all.

```
while (cNode.hasMoreElements()) {
  Ogre::SceneNode* curr = (Ogre::SceneNode *)cNode.getNext();
  switch (rand() % 5)
  {
  case 0:
    _roleNode = curr->createChild(nodename.str());
    _signEntity = manager->createEntity("Barrel.mesh");
    _roleNode->attachObject(_signEntity);
    break;
  /* ... */
  default:
    break;
  }
}
```